# React Native - RnDiffApp

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

Does anyone know where this comes from and what purpose it stores?
I see it on the Android side in file `android/app/BUCK`

```
android_build_config(
    name = "build_config",
    package = "com.rndiffapp",
)

android_resource(
    name = "res",
    package = "com.rndiffapp",
    res = "src/main/res",
)
```

...and on the IOS side I see it everywhere (and its causing issues)...including in `\myAppName\ios\myAppName\AppDelegate.m`

```
@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  RCTBridge *bridge = [[RCTBridge alloc] initWithDelegate:self launchOptions:launchOptions];
  RCTRootView *rootView = [[RCTRootView alloc] initWithBridge:bridge
                                                   moduleName:@"RnDiffApp"
                                            initialProperties:nil];
```

I heard that `react-native upgrade` uses `rn-diff-purge` under the hood and Im wondering if me trying `react-native upgrade` caused all this mess.  Im wondering if theres a way to undo this as Im getting trouble building in Xcode..see below

```
No such file or directory: /xxx/myAppName/ios/RnDiffApp/main.m
No such file or directory: /xxx/myAppName/ios/RnDiffApp/AppDelegate.m
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had this happen recently after an upgrade failure.  Look at your ios/Podfile and change references of RnDiffApp to YourAppName.  You can also do a global search for other files that may be affected.  In my case it was only Podfile.

After updating Podfile I found the following commands needed:

```
cd ios
rm Podfile.lock
pod install
cd ..
```

Comment: I wonder if this happen because I changed my App name, so that it could no more find them with old app name.